# How can I get my Chrome extension to stop when i move to another tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've done the tutorial on Chrome extension on the google developer chrome [site](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview)
and am trying to create my own. Basically I want to make an extension that, when the browser action is clicked, makes you able to click on any sentence of a paragraph on a page and highlight it. When you move to another tab, you have to click it again to activate it. The problem is that, unfortunately it doesn't seem to stop when I move to another tab or navigate to another site. How can I make it stop?

Here is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Page highlight ",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
   "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.11.1.min.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
   "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "highlight sentence on click"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I added a jQuery file to use jQuery, and my `myscript.js` file, which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('p').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).text().split(/([\.\?!])(?= )/).map(
            function(v){return '<span class=sentence>'+v+'</span>'}
        ));
    });

   $('.sentence').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight")
   });
});
```

It basically looks for the text in any paragraph then cuts it into sentences and puts them in a span with `class="sentence"`, so I can click any sentence and toggle the CSS class, which stile is defined in my `styles.css` file where I just highlights the sentence in yellow, here it is:

```
.highlight{
    background: yellow;
}
```

Now, when I click the browser action (extension icon) it  activates and I can click a sentence to highlight it, but I want it to stop when I go to another tab or navigate to another site. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

It looks like you didn't understand the behavior of a browser action. If you want to control your extension using a browser action you will need to add a listener to the `onClick` event of the `browserAction`, so when the user clicks it you can inject the scripts and the CSSs inside the current page.

### Solution

First of all, edit your `manifest.json`, you don't need the `"content_scripts"` field, because you will only need inject your script when the user clicks. So add the `"background"` field for your `background.js` script and the permission for the `tabs` API. Here is what your `manifest.json` will look like after this changes:

```
{
  "name": "Page highlight ",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
   ],
   "background" {
       "scripts": ["background.js"]
   },
   "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "highlight sentence on click"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Before editing `background.js`, you'll have to **remove the `$(document).ready(...)` listener**, because if you insert your script into a page clicking the browser action, it is most likely inserted into a page that has already loaded, so the ready listener will not work. Also, your code is wrong, because the `.map()` method returns an array, so you have to `.join()` it before replacing the html of the element. I edited it for you. Your new `myscript.js` will be this:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().split(/([\.\?!])(?= )/).map(
        function(v){return '<span class="sentence">'+v+'</span>'}
    ).join(''));
});

$('.sentence').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Ok, now in your `background.js` you need to **add a listener to the `chrome.browserAction.onClick`** event and **inject the scripts and the CSSs** you need using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` and `chrome.tabs.insertCSS()` when the user clicks the browser action.

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) and [`chrome.scripting.insertCSS()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-insertCSS) (with the `scripting` permission) instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "jquery-1.11.1.min.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "myscript.js"});
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: "style.css"});
});
```

That's all you need, now when you click the extension's browser action the script will be injected into the page and you'll be able to highlight your sentences.

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing happens when the I click the browser action button and then proceed to click the sentences on a webpage to highlight them like myscript.js says?

Comment: @babaysteps I edited my answer, check it out. I also added a download link for a working example you can find [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zsfj3c8bry7jm96/extension-26373792.zip).